# "while true" statement not working

Tags: python-3.x

```
number_of_players = int(input("Please input the number of players playing: "))
recorded_players = []
for counter in range(0, number_of_players):
    name_of_friend = str(input("Input players first name: "))
    recorded_players.append(name_of_friend)
your_name = str(input("Please enter your name: "))
while True:
    import random
    random_name = random.choice(recorded_players)
    if recorded_players != your_name:
        break
friend_name = (random_name.upper())
selected_name = (your_name.upper())
gift_price = (len(friend_name)) * 2
print(selected_name,"You have bought a gift for your friend", friend_name, "which costs £", gift_price)
```

Can anyone help to point me in the right direction here, the while True loop doesn't break when I want it to. giving me the same name as I put in, I would like the loop to repeat as many times until the names are not the same, working with two or more players;

```
Please input the number of players playing: 2
Input players first name: Bob
Input players first name: Alice
Please enter your name: Bob
BOB You have bought a gift for your friend BOB which costs £ 6
```

As you can see, some of the time the program does not work as expected and I cannot seem to find a workaround to this problem, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You are comparing list to a string. And neither of those variables change inside the loop.

Comment: @gre_gor so I would need to convert the list into a string to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your while loop, you are comparing two variable that don't change. And they are even a different type.

You probably meant to compare your random name with your own:

```
while True:
    import random
    random_name = random.choice(recorded_players)
    if random_name != your_name:
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
import random
# want to run all variable from start(first change)
while True:
    number_of_players = int(input("Please input the number of players playing: "))
    recorded_players = []
    for counter in range(0, number_of_players):
        name_of_friend = str(input("Input players first name: "))
        recorded_players.append(name_of_friend)
#please be noted the list has elements refer to name recorded_player
    your_name = str(input("Please enter your name: "))
    random_name = random.choice(recorded_players)
#please note recorded_player linked with all list elements
#please note random_name linked with choice only (one element)
#so right pick for (if) to compare is random_name(single element)(second change)
    if random_name == your_name:
#according to problem want to break when name same so != or ==(third change)
        break
    friend_name = (random_name.upper())
    selected_name = (your_name.upper())
    gift_price = (len(friend_name)) * 2
    print(selected_name,"You have bought a gift for your friend", friend_name, "which costs £", gift_price)
```

Comment: This is just repeating the question's code with the same mistake.

Comment: i think the edit is what desired

Comment: Sorry, I did not see what you changed in the code. Code-only answers are not encouraged, please add some explanation what you did and what is the purpose.

Comment: Try to describe your solution, a chunck of code is not enough for the answer to be clear

Answer (score 0):

import random
while True:
number_of_players = int(input("Please input the number of players playing: "))
recorded_players = []
for counter in range(0, number_of_players):
name_of_friend = str(input("Input players first name: "))
recorded_players.append(name_of_friend)
your_name = str(input("Please enter your name: "))

```
random_name = random.choice(recorded_players)
if str(random_name) == str(your_name):
    continue
else:
    friend_name = (random_name.upper())
    selected_name = (your_name.upper())
    gift_price = (len(friend_name)) * 2
    print(selected_name,"You have bought a gift for your friend", friend_name, "which costs £", gift_price)
    print(id(selected_name),"....",id(friend_name))
```

Comment: its for jump over desired result

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).